# Selenium python verifying text in the multiple <td>

Tags: python, selenium

I have the below text on the webpage which i need to verify:

```
IT  1   $2.00   8%  row1            
Sales   2   $20.00  30% row2
```

The problem I am having is each of the text is in a different td(see screenshot below).

[image]

Is it possible to verify the all of the text at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can locate all the `td` elements inside the row and "join" the texts.

Something along these lines:

```
desired = "IT 1 $2.00 8% row1"

row = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table tr")  # TODO: use your actual locator to select the row
actual = " ".join([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]).strip()

assert row == actual
```